# Split one file into multiple file based on some conditions

Tags: bash, unix

I have a file with 1 months data for Feburary and I 
need to split file by each day i.e. split `Feb` file to `Feb_1`,`Feb_2`...`Feb_29`.

Here is my logic:

```
Inputfile= $1
monthname = "Feb"
while getopts :
datefield="1"
outfile="Feb_1"

while read line    
do
s = `echo "$line" | awk '{print $2}'`
t = `echo "$line" | awk '{print $3}'`
if [ "$s" = "$monthname" ]
    if [ "$t" = "$datefield" ] 
         echo $line > "$outfile"
    else
         datefield = $t
         outfile =$monthaname"_"$t
         echo $line > "$outfile"
    fi
else
  echo $line > "$outfile"
fi 
done < "$inputfile"
```

but `s = echo "$line" | awk '{print $2}'`

this is not giving me the second word as I am using `$2` its asking for a second command line argument. I tried putting `'` before `$2` as below.

```
s = echo "$line" | awk '{print '$2}'
```

In that case its thrown a new error suppose first line is `Wed Feb 1` its throwing error as `Wed Feb 1` does not exist.

Here is sample data:

```
Wed Feb 1 00:10:00 cpu usage    
KLOGENT.exe 3068 SYSTEM 00 0:00:00 17345K 15467 BELOW NORMAL    
SGHT.exe 3868 SYSTEM 00 0:00:00 18845K 15499 BELOW NORMAL    
.......    
.......    
Wed Feb 1 00:15:00 cpu usage    
KLTREENT.exe 3068 SYSTEM 00 0:00:00 17345K 15767 BELOW NORMAL    
KJTRT.exe 3868 SYSTEM 00 0:00:00 18845K 13699 BELOW NORMAL    
..............   
...........    
Wed Feb 1 23:55:00 cpu usage    
HTR.exe 3068 SYSTEM 00 0:00:00 1785K 4532 BELOW NORMAL    
KLU.exe 3868 SYSTEM 00 0:00:00 15645K 678 BELOW NORMAL    
...............   
.................   
Thu Feb 2 00:10:00 cpu usage
JUYT.exe 3068 SYSTEM 00 0:00:00 143245K 157767 BELOW NORMAL   
GFD.exe 3868 SYSTEM 00 0:00:00 18845K 879 BELOW NORMAL    
.........................    
.......................    
Thu Feb 28 00:15:00 cpu usage    
FRE.exe 3068 SYSTEM 00 0:00:00 143245K 157767 BELOW NORMAL    
YUT.exe 3868 SYSTEM 00 0:00:00 18845K 879 BELOW NORMAL    
............................    
...................    
Thu Feb 28 23:55:00 cpu usage    
TRE.exe 3068 SYSTEM 00 0:00:00 143245K 157767 BELOW NORMAL    
KJH.exe 3868 SYSTEM 00 0:00:00 18845K 879 BELOW NORMAL
```

Comment: can you add sample data from the input file?

Comment: Terrible formatting! Don't add non-answers as answer update the question. You **really** need to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 2):

Staring into my crystal ball to determine the input data, you want:

```
awk '{print > $2 "_" $3 }' input-file
```

or possibly

```
awk '$2 == "Feb" {print > $2 "_" $3 }' input-file
```

It would be much simpler to provide a solution if the actual format of the input were known.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/Feb/{file=$2"_"$3}{print $0>file".txt"}' your_log
```

Comment: Way more efficient than my idea of using grep and iterating though my 66GB file 200 times :)

Change it to this to show progress.

`pv your_log | awk '/Feb/{file=$2"_"$3}{print $0>file".txt"}'`